# Programs requiring SUDO authentication not launching from Unity search launcher and Synapse [Ubuntu, 16.04]

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher, sudo

So, basically what's in the tittle. I can execute any installed program with both Synapse and Unity, but if it requires SUDO authentication (like Synaptic, Y-PPA manager) it doesn't launch.

It's clearly a problem with policykit or something like that. I'm not an expert and so I cannot backtrack or troubleshoot the problem by myself...

Thanks!

---

First Edit

Just some more details:
- Launching said programs in terminal with $sudo works fine.
- Launching said programs in terminal with $gksudo also works fine, the password popup appears.

---

Second Edit

Upon request from @steeldriver in the comment section

```
$ synaptic-pkexec
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR com.ubuntu.pkexec.synaptic ===
Authentication is required to run the Synaptic Package Manager
Authenticating as: [my name] ([my username])
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
```

Comment: Are there any error messages that might be useful if you run something like `synaptic-pkexec` or `pkexec synaptic` in a terminal?

Comment: Hi @steeldriver, thank you for your comment. Yes there is, I'll add it to the post shortly.

Comment: OK thanks - and just to confirm, you are running this locally (not for example remotely via xrdp or vnc)?

Comment: Yes, locally. I've updated the post

Comment: Is the authentication agent running? You can check with (for example) `ps -ef | grep [p]olkit`

Comment: I think so, it shows `root       891     1  0 09:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug`

Comment: You should also see something like `/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` I think

Comment: I don't have such. But I ran `sudo /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` and now I can start Synaptic from the launcher. is there a way to force `polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` to start at start-up?

Comment: It should be started automatically by the /etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop file - you will need to figure out why that's not happening. Sorry I need to step away now - good luck.

Comment: Thanks, it should be fine. The file you mentioned is there, and it looks like it's as it should be... I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with the same situation of `/usr/liub/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug` showing instead of `/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1`. @romanovzky: were you able to figure out a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `authentication-agent` is not running. Run the following command to run the agent

```
/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
```

If it works then run that on `startup`.